# Skip substring in String.Contains in Java

Tags: java

For a given string

```
String name = "Test";
String welcomeMessage = "Welcome" + name + ", You have notification!";
```

How can we check if welcomeMessage contains "Welcome, you have notification" substring by escaping name variable as name variable keeps on changing?

I want to achieve

```
welcomeMessage.contains("Welcome, You have notification!"); //to return true
```

What would be the best way to skip name variable?

Comment: `welcomeMessage.contains("Welcome%s, You have notification!".formatted(name));`? --- As an aside: in the `welcomeMessage`, you are most probably missing a blank (`"Welcome" + name + ", You have notification!"` -> `"Welcome " + name + ", You have notification!"`)

Comment: But the real question is: why do you want this?

Comment: Does this work for your case? `welcomeMessage.contains("You have notification!")`. I imagine this would be sufficient to check.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `welcomeMessage.matches(".*Welcome[^,]*, You have notification!.*")`?

Comment: You could also do: `welcomeMessage.startsWith("Welcome ") && welcomeMessage.endsWith(", You have notification!)`

Comment: Did you inadvertently omit a SPACE after the word “Welcome”?

Answer (score 5):

## `String#startsWith` & `endsWith`

The `String` class provides specific methods:

- [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))
- [`endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))

Example:

```
boolean containsPhrases = 
    message.startsWith( "Welcome" )
    &&
    message.endsWith( ", You have notification!" )
;
```

Comment: Good answer. That's better from the performance perspective than employing the regex engine to do this job. Even it seems like there are two calls instead of one, they are relatively cheap - internally only bytes that correspond to bytes of the given *prefix/suffix* would be checked, not the whole string. And this solution is more friendly to a beginner as well.

Answer (score 2):

very simple

```
String name = "Test";
String welcomeMessage = "Welcome" + name + ", You have notification!";
            System.out.println(welcomeMessage + " matches " + welcomeMessage.matches("Welcome.+You have notification!"));
```

Answer (score 2):

With `matches` on a *regular expression*. There are some special regex characters that need to be escaped with a backslash, twice `\\` in a regex.

```
welcomeMessage.matches("Welcome .*, you have notification\\!");
```

`.*` stands for `.` = any character without line breaks, and `*` = repeat the previous 0 or more times. So any string.